# How to set the order of widgets in QGridLayout

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to put a `QPushButton` on top of a `PlotWidget`. My current code always has the plot widget on top of the button. How can I bring the button to the front of the `QGridLayout`?

Or is there a better way in `PyQt5` to overlay widgets?

I have tried using `.raise__()` and `.lower__()` neither worked as expected. 
As far as I found there is no way in `PyQt5` to set a z value
Changing the order of adding the widgets to the `QGridLayout` had no effect

The `PlotWindow` class is used in a Stacked widget in a Window controller class as well as some other classes

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.plot = PlotWindow(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.plot)

        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.plot)
        self.show()

class PlotWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlotWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        plot_frame = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()

        self.connect_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Connect", self)

        plot_wrapper_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        plot_wrapper_layout.addWidget(plot_frame, 0, 0, 12, 12)
        plot_wrapper_layout.addWidget(self.connect_btn, 11, 11, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(plot_wrapper_layout)
```

Expecting: Button to be visible on top of the graph in the bottom right corner

Result: The connect button is hidden behind the plot widget

Comment: Try `plot_frame = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(self)`. That puts the graph widget before the push button in `PlotWindow.children()` which changes the order in which they are rendered.

Comment: @Heike that's interesting. I suppose that's due to the intricate nature of PlotWidgets (which probably reparents its children only during initialization). But, interestingly enough, if you don't set a parent for both the PlotWidget *and* QPushButton, you get the expected result too.

Comment: @Heike that fixed it thank you, overlooked that.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah that also worked removed the self from the QPushButton had the same result, although I would guess doing that wouldn't be good practice?

Comment: @Dustin2902 It's not *always* necessary, as `addWidget` *uses* [`addItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget): "*ownership* of QLayoutItem [aware, *not* the widget!] is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it". This means that, at least for *standard* Qt widgets, their parent **ownership** (and the parent of their direct children) *should* be transferred to the layout's widget. But. This doesn't mean the widget's parent automatically becomes the widget the layout is using, expecially if the `changeEvent` is not overloaded as basic QWidgets do.

Answer (score 0):

plot_frame = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(self). That puts the graph widget before the push button in PlotWindow.children() which changes the order in which they are rendered.

Heikie's comment fixed the issue